# Reading from a text file into a vector of objects in a class- writing in another txt file

Tags: c++

I have changed the code, now the program reads teh file form students.txt correctly, but still calculated from user input instead of students.txt
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

//Declaring class Student   

class Student
{
private:

  string newName;
  int newScore1;
  int newScore2;
  int newScore3;
  float newFinal;

public:
  // No argument constructors
  Student ()

 {
  newName     = " ";
  newScore1   = 0;
  newScore2   = 0;
  newScore3   = 0;
  newFinal    = 0.00;

 }
 //all arguements constructors
 Student (string name, int score1, int score2, int score3, float final)

 {
 newName     = name;
 newScore1   = score1;
 newScore2   = score2;
 newScore3   = score3;
 newFinal      = final;
 } 
 //getters
 string getName() const
 {
  return newName;
 }
 int getScore1() const
 {
 return newScore1;
 }
 int getScore2()const
 {
 return newScore2;
 }
 int getScore3()const
 {
 return newScore3;
 }

 float getFinal () const
 {
  return newFinal;
 }

 //Setters
 void setName(string name)
 {
  newName = name;
 }
 void setScore1(int score1)
 {
 newScore1=score1;
 }
 void setScore2(int score2)
 {
  newScore2=score2;
 }
 void setScore3 (int score3)
 {
 newScore3 = score3;
 }

 void setFinal (float final)
 {
    newFinal = final;
 }


};
//asks for number of students, 
// function asks for input to fill in vector
//sorts the inputs to get max 2 scores out of 3 
//puts the data in a vector of class Student
//Sends data to a text file students.txt
 void fillvector(vector <Student>& newMyClass)

{
 string name;
 float score1;
 float score2;
 float score3;
 float final;
 float tmp;
 cout << "Please enter the number of Students: " << endl;
 int classSize;
 cin >> classSize;
 for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i ++)
   {
   cout << "Enter Student's name" << endl;
   cin >> name;
   cout << "Enter Student's Score 1" << endl;
   cin >> score1;
   cout << "Enter Student's Score 2" << endl;
   cin >> score2;
   cout << "Enter Student's Score 3" << endl;
   cin >> score3;
   if(score1>score2)
     {
      float tmp = score1;
      score1 = score2;
      score2 = tmp;
     }
   if(score1>score3)
     {
     float tmp = score1;
     score1=score3;
     score3 = tmp;
     }
   if(score2>score3)
    {
     float tmp = score2;
     score2=score3;
     score3=tmp;
    }

  final = (score2+score3)/2;

  Student newStudent (name, score1, score2, score3, final);
  newMyClass.push_back(newStudent);
  cout << endl;

  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("students.txt", std::ofstream::out |std::ofstream::app );
  myfile << name<< setw(5)<< score1<< setw(5)<<score2<<setw(5)  <<score3<<setw(5)<<final<<setw(5)<<endl;
  myfile.close();
  cout << "Copied to students.txt" << endl;


   }
    cout << endl;
}
//reads data from textfile students.txt
//calculated teh minimum scores and maximum scores
//sends the minimum and maximum scores to text file Results.txt
void readToVector(vector <Student>& newMyClass)

{
    string name;
float score1;
float score2;
float score3;
float finalScore;
Student newStudent (name, score1, score2, score3, finalScore);
unsigned int size = newMyClass.size();
ifstream fin("students.txt");
if (fin.is_open())
  {cout << "File open" << endl;
    while(fin >> name >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> finalScore)
      {
    newStudent.setName(name);
    newStudent.setScore1(score1);
    newStudent.setScore2(score2);
    newStudent.setScore3(score3);
    newStudent.setFinal(finalScore);
    newMyClass.push_back(newStudent);
    //cout << newStudent.getName() << newStudent.getFinal() << endl;

      }
     fin.close();
    cout << endl;
    Student studWMaxScore  = newMyClass[0];
    float maxscore = studWMaxScore.getFinal();

for (unsigned int i =0; i < size; i++) 
{
    if (maxscore < newMyClass[i].getFinal())
  { 
   maxscore = newMyClass[i].getFinal();
   studWMaxScore = newMyClass[i];

  }

}
cout << "Maximum Score is " << maxscore << endl;
  ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open ("Result.txt", std::ofstream::out  );
   myfile << "Maximum Score" << endl;
   myfile << maxscore << endl;
   myfile << "Name of the student with maximum score is " <<  endl;
   myfile << studWMaxScore.getName() << endl <<  endl; 
   // myfile.close();
   cout << "Copied to Results.txt" << endl; 

Student stuWMinScore = newMyClass[0];
float minscore = stuWMinScore.getFinal();
for (unsigned int i =0; i < size; i++)
{
  if (minscore > newMyClass[i].getFinal())
    {
      minscore = newMyClass[i].getFinal();
      stuWMinScore = newMyClass[i];

    }   
}
cout << "Minimum Score is " << minscore << endl; 
// ofstream myfile;
//  myfile.open ("Result.txt", std::ofstream::out );
 myfile << "Mimimum Score" << endl;
myfile << minscore << endl;
myfile << "Name of the student with minimum score is " <<  endl;
myfile << stuWMinScore.getName() << endl <<  endl;
//  myfile.close();
cout << "Copied to Results.txt" << endl;
  }
else
  cout << "file in not open" << '\n';

}


//prints out the name and scores of each student
void printVector (const vector<Student>& newMyClass)

{
unsigned int size = newMyClass.size();
for (unsigned int i =0; i < size; i++)

  {
cout << "Student name is: "<< newMyClass[i].getName() << endl;
cout << "Student Score 1 is "<< newMyClass[i].getScore1()<< endl;
cout << "Student Score 2 is "<< newMyClass[i].getScore2()<< endl;
cout << "Student Score 3 is "<< newMyClass[i].getScore3()<< endl;
cout << "Student Final Score is " << newMyClass[i].getFinal() << endl;
cout << endl; 
  }

}




int main ()

{
vector <Student> myClass;
fillvector (myClass);
readToVector(myClass);
    printVector(myClass); 
}
```

Comment: You cut off a part of the function. Where are min and max calculated? Is students.txt in the same directory as the program?

Comment: Please provide more complete code (including the Student class) and an example of the students.txt file.

Comment: hi, Thanks for responding, I have added the class definitions and the min max calculations.

Comment: Please read the [MVC page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. The code you provided is still not complete and is far from compiling. Moreover you did not provided the student.txt file. Oh and please fix indentation.

Comment: When you get this working. You should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get it reviewed for better practice.

Comment: @LokiAstari will do..!

Comment: @steiner does this look readable now? excuse the newbie a little pls.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core of bug looks to be right here:

```
while(fin >> name >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> finalScore)
{
    newStudent.setName(name);
    newStudent.setScore1(score1);
    newStudent.setScore2(score2);
    newStudent.setScore3(score3);
    newStudent.setFinal(finalScore);
}
fin.close();
newMyClass.push_back(newStudent);
```

Once the indentation is fixed, it's easy to see that `newStudent` is only pushed into the vector *after* the file has been completely read. OP should be getting the last student into the vector, but none of the others. Since OP probably wants all of the students in the file in the vector,

```
while(fin >> name >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> finalScore)
{
    newStudent.setName(name);
    newStudent.setScore1(score1);
    newStudent.setScore2(score2);
    newStudent.setScore3(score3);
    newStudent.setFinal(finalScore);
    newMyClass.push_back(newStudent); <- moved push_back to here
}
fin.close(); <- probably not necessary
```

<strike>Can't verify the rest of the code because there doesn't seem to be a definition or assignment of `size`--Crom only knows if those for loops are covering the correct ground--or the  validity of the input because there is no provided input file. OP may be reading exactly nothing if the parsing rules are wrong. Debugger would figure that out much faster than another Stack Overflow post.</strike>(OP has since addressed this)

New stuff.

I don't see why the input doesn't parse either. First make sure the file is encoded as ASCII text. I do not know what tools you have to do this on your computer. I use a hex editor, lets you see the file in byte values rather than characters, to see if the characters are not matching their expected ASCII values. A text editor may be converting for you and hiding the differences.

For example, often a UTF-8 encoded file will look exactly the same as an ASCII file except for a bit of binary at the beginning marking informing the reader program that it is a UTF-8 file and may contain non-ASCII.

If it isn't, there's the problem. Re-save the file as an ASCII file. If it is an ASCII file, time to minimize. Write a small program that does nothing but open the file, read it token by token, and see which token fails to parse. Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("students.txt");
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        int line = 0;

        while(true) // loop forever
        {
            line++;
            if (!fin >> name)
            {
                std::cout << "Could not read name on line " << line << std::endl;
                break; // exit loop
            }
            if (!fin >> score1)
            {
                std::cout << "Could not read score1 on line " << line << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            if (!fin >> score2)
            {
                std::cout << "Could not read score2 on line " << line << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            if (!fin >> score3)
            {
                std::cout << "Could not read score3 on line " << line << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            if (!fin >> finalScore)
            {
                std::cout << "Could not read finalScore on line " << line << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << "Could not open file" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Once you know where the file fails, you are in great position to ask a new question. This one is sprawling a bit too much.

Comment: Thanks, I tried moving the push_back into the while loop, doesnt affect the result. it still is reading only the user input to the result.txt

Comment: Since the size is determined by the no. of students entered by the user, i have tried using newMyClass.size(); to get the size.

Comment: When you run your code with your development environment's debugger do you ever enter the `while` loop? Or heck, go old school. Put a cout inside the while loop to print the student's name. No name, no student and your parsing rules are wrong for your input file.

Comment: That appears to be the problem, but I am not able to find a correct syntax to parse it. showed the code to an expert, he told me to fix this only, but I am not able to get it correct after trying out many ways..

Comment: Do what steiner has been asking for and add a few lines of the file that contains the student list. Most likely one of the input tokens does not parse to a floating point number. For example, "John Smith 3.14 99.6 82.0 666.13" will read John into name and then Smith as score1. Obviously that won't work well.

Comment: Have added the students.txt example. I believe there is no way to attach the file itself..

Comment: @VivekPhull added a few more things to try.

Comment: tks. Did try to chack, and improved the code a bit, but still not getting the correct calculation of result.txt from students.txt.

Comment: Hi, will appreciate further help.